# AccessViolation when calling unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, interop, erlang, unmanaged, erl-interface

When calling an unmanaged Dll from a c# application I get an `AccessViolationException`. The strange thing is that the exported function has no arguments, so the problem is not in the Marshalling of data. The function gets no argument and just returns an integer. Also note that calling convention is not an issue. An identical function with the same zero arguments and integer return value (but different name) works just fine. What are the remaining  candidate reasons that such a call could cause this exception considering the fact that marshalling and calling convention is ruled out?

UPDATE: The dll function is correct because if called from other unmanaged code through plain linking, then it works perfectly.

UPDATE 2: Everything is compiled and run on 32 bit. I tried Win XP SP2 and Vista. Here is an interesting fact: On Vista Systems it works like a charm. On XP it fails.

UPDATE 3: I didnt get the source code but I learned what essentially this dll does, so i tried to reproduce the problem with my own dll. Here is the story: The original dll is some kind of a wrapper to ei.lib (Erlang's c interface library). It exports some helper funcs. So  to reproduce the problem I have made a wrapper dll around ei.lib which exports only one function, namely "test()". I did that so I wouldnt mess with marshalling and stuff. I wanted just to test an initialization, connecting and sending a message. So this test() func of my dll just calls `ei_connect_init()`, then `ei_connect()` and finaly `ei_reg_send()`, with arguments hardcoded inside. The problem is that if I call this dll and use the test() function from another unmanaged code, it works ok. Message is sent. But when I call it from c# through DllImport then it works only on Vista. Not on XP. On XP it fails with a AccessViolationException on the .net layer. I ve tried to trace down the problem and I see that from inside my dll, any call to `ei_connect()`, or any attempt to read `erl_errno` (these are defined in ei.lib) when running on XP and being called by managed code result in trying to read or write protected memory so the app crashes. It cant be something trivial since it works on Vista and it works when called by unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think i know the problem: the ei.lib uses TLS (Thread Local Storage). In the file `ei_pthreads.c` of the ei interface source code there is this snippet:

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
#ifdef USE_DECLSPEC_THREAD
/* Define (and initialize) the variable __erl_errno */
volatile __declspec(thread) int __erl_errno = 0;
#else
static volatile DWORD errno_tls_index = TLS_OUT_OF_INDEXES;
static LONG volatile tls_init_mutex = 0;
#endif
#endif
```

If `USE_DECLSPEC_THREAD` is not defined then, lower in the source file, TLS Api is used instead.
Now, from msdn i found that:

> On Windows operating systems before
>   Windows Vista, `__declspec( thread )`
>   has some limitations. If a DLL
>   declares any nonlocal data or object
>   as `__declspec( thread )`, it can cause
>   a protection fault if dynamically
>   loaded. After the DLL is loaded with
>   LoadLibrary, it causes system failure
>   whenever the code references the
>   nonlocal `__declspec( thread )` data.
>   Because the global variable space for
>   a thread is allocated at run time, the
>   size of this space is based on a
>   calculation of the requirements of the
>   application plus the requirements of
>   all the DLLs that are statically
>   linked. When you use LoadLibrary, you
>   cannot extend this space to allow for
>   the thread local variables declared
>   with `__declspec( thread )`. Use the TLS
>   APIs, such as TlsAlloc, in your DLL to
>   allocate TLS if the DLL might be
>   loaded with LoadLibrary.

So , since I use the erl interface libs provided with the precompiled binary distribution of erlang for windows, I wonder if they defined `USE_DECLSPEC_THREAD` when compiling those binaries. If not then I am in dead end and I will try something else to do my job with. If they did define it then I must install cygwin and recompile the sources without defining it. (Yikes...).

FINAL UPDATE: Indeed this was the problem. I had to install cygwin and compile the erl_interface code again without defining `USE_DECLSPEC_TRHEAD`. Also there is another little catch when recompiling, a tiny change is needed so that definition of `_WIN32_WINNT` happens before inclusion of winbase.h because after the omission of `USE_DECLSPEC_THREAD` the code uses SwitchToThread which is defined in winbase.h only if `_WIN32_WINNT` is defined and with a value greater than 0x400.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when the unmanaged code causes a memory access violation. Check to see that the unmanaged function is correct.  If you have the source for the unmanaged code you can also [enable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf(VS.80).aspx)  the debugger to step into the unmanaged code and see where the problem is.

Comment: also, i dont have access to source code, i ll try to get at least the object with debug info and give the debugger a shot.

Comment: Does the unmanaged library have some sort of static initialization function that should be called before use?  Also make sure that there is no 32 <-> 64 bit mismatch.  If the unmanaged code is 32 bit and the managed is running as 64 you might also get this exception.

Comment: I used the unmanaged dll in the c# by calling it exaclty the same way as called by an unmanaged test app. 1 call of the offending function. How could c# call affect a static initialization in a way different than the call from the unmanaged test app?

Comment: Some libraries require you to call a static init function before use, it sounds like yours does not.

Did you investigate the other suggestion?  I have had issues in the past calling unmanaged 32 bit code when the managed assembly is built with the platform target equal to AnyCPU and then run on a 64 bit OS.